# How to secure a raw UDP listener in Azure on a static IP address

Tags: azure, security, udp, static-ip-address

We need to listen for UDP messages from a vendor who wants to send a single small package once per hour to minimize battery drain. I cannot whitelist the client IP addresses but also need to prevent DOS and garbage being dumped into the system. Any help is most welcomed.

Comment: Whoever voted to close the question, please state a reason why it should be closed.